# How to tell Google a page has moved?

Tags: seo

We have #1 and #2 spots we would like to keep, but because of the way things were jumbled we have to migrate to a new domain.

We do not want the new domain to be penalized for duplicate content, we want it to naturally take the spot on Google.

How do we tell Google our page has moved?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

301 redirects are the recommended way to do this according to [Google themselves](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93633). I tend to perform 301's using a .htaccess file (a few different methods [here](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/301-redirect-with-mod_rewrite-or-redirectmatch.html)) but it can also be done using PHP like this:

```
header('Location: '.$newlocation, true, 301)
```

Comment: +1 Correct solution, Google link to back it up and PHP example. What more can one want?

Comment: You can do that with just one call: `header('Location: '.$newlocation, true, 301)`

Comment: You posted this answer in 34 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

What seengee user has answered is perfect.
Have a look to [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools) too; there's a specific option for Address change.

**Change of address**

If you're planning to move your site to a new domain, use the Change of Address tool to tell Google about your new URL. This will help us update our index faster and smooth the transition for your users.

For best results, follow these steps:

1. Set up the new site

   Review our guidelines for moving your site to a new domain. Set up your content on your new domain, then make sure all internal links point to the new domain.
2. Redirect all traffic from the old site

   Use a [301](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=93633&hl=en) redirect to permanently redirect the pages on your old site to your new site. This tells users and search engines that your site has permanently moved. Ask webmasters to update their links to point to your new domain and make sure incoming links to your old site are redirected correctly using the 301 redirects.
3. Add your new site to Webmaster Tools

   Make sure you have added and verified your new domain.
4. Tell us the URL of your new domain

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools add both domains there and then, go Change of address.

Answer (score 0):

Http 301 Request is used for Permanent Redirect the old website's content,URL and Links to New Website URL. Google Never Penalize the New Website for Duplicate content.

Answer (score 0):

what about "Keyword" you use in meta for performing in SERP result. After redirection how you manage them.

position before Redirection , after redirection have same OR not.

AS SEO purpose don't make Redirection withour proper plan. First make proper optimization of "B" page before "A" redirect ( 301, 302 ) "B" page.

Dont make 302 Redirect , its spammy after 3 months, why within 20 Days SERP catche show "B" page instead of "A" page.

in the end : Before Redirection - Optimize the Destination URl - for Benefit SEOand business

Have a Nice Day ... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Google itself detect your web page if you implemented the `301`, `302` or `404` redirection. But if you want to tell google that you have moved your page then:

- Go to `google webmaster tool`
- In `Crawl` section there is an option of `Fetch as Google`.
- Just enter your url and check the fetch status, you will find that google will index your new url.

Answer (score 0):

in google webmaster tools click on change of site address. 
firstly you need to put content on new website where you want to redirect the website. 
redirect usingold website by using HTTP 301 code and after verify in google webmaster tools.

Answer (score 0):

Do 301 redirects. This will tell the search engines that the pages have moved and where they are now. This also associates the old URL with the new URL for Google which means all of your old incoming links will now be redirects to your new pages. Also use [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools) to submit XML sitemap.

Answer (score 0):

In both Google and Bing Webmaster tools, you can notify a change of address. I will warn you, however, that when changing domains, you're not going to keep your current rankings.

Submit a change of address notice in Webmaster tools

Do 1:1 page redirecting (redirect all other pages that can't be mapped to a similar page to your homepage)

Submit an up-to-date sitemap

This should help:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106?hl=en
http://moz.com/blog/achieving-an-seo-friendly-domain-migration-the-infographic